# Avalanche Consensus and how better it is than Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, ether, evm, consensus, avalanche

Which consensus mechanism do Avalanche currently uses and is it better than ethereum and other EVM compatible blockchain and apart from consensus what others benefits does avalanche provides us?